# Marshalling Between /MD and /MT Runtime Libraries

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2010, dll

I have third party libs that were compiled as `/MTd` and `/MT` respectively. These cannot be changed. I am consuming them using a `MT` dll.

How can I cross boundaries into `/MD` dll land in order to satisfy the requires for `/CLI` and have any hopes of calling these third party libs from C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fairly easy: COM-style. That is to say, do not assume you can pass C++ types (because the C++ libraries differ) but instead pass all data using the native COM mechanism such as `BSTR`/`_bstr_t`.